# Getting Code Directory Hash for the application macOS

Tags: macos

I want to get the **Code Directory Hash (unique hash)** for my running application on MAC OS.
how to achieve this programatically on MAC OS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hash with the `codesign` command:

```sh
codesign -dv /path/to/application.app
```

There is a nice [man-page](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/codesign/#:%7E:text=The%20codesign%20command%20is%20used,options%20to%20modify%20its%20behavior.) where you can find more information about the command.